# JavaFX - TitledPane not showing JFXButton Text inside TitledPane title graphics

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, accordion

I'm making sidebar menu with Accordion TitledPane, Whenever I'm adding JFXButton inside TitledPane's title graphics it fit well inside it but Button Text not showing. I have added fontAwesomeIcon inside button, I can see the fontAwesome Icon but not able to see Button text. Also when TiledPane expanded JFXButton text not showing up.

Below is my FXML code

```
<VBox layoutY="76.0" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="664.0" prefWidth="250.0" style="-fx-background-color: #E5DEF3;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="76.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="250.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <Accordion nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT">
              <panes>
                <TitledPane fx:id="tt1" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" cache="true" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" graphicTextGap="4.0">
                     <graphic>
                        <JFXButton fx:id="ttbtn1" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="218.0">
                           <graphic>
                              <FontAwesomeIconView size="1.5em" />
                           </graphic>
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                     </graphic>
                     <content>
                        <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefWidth="100.0">
                           <children>
                              <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="271.0" />
                              <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="271.0" />
                              <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="271.0" />
                              <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="271.0" />
                              <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="271.0" />
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" text="untitled 2">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                     <graphic>
                        <JFXButton alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="217.0">
                           <graphic>
                              <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="HOME" size="1.5em" />
                           </graphic>
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                     </graphic>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" text="untitled 3">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                     <graphic>
                        <JFXButton alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" graphicTextGap="10.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="215.0">
                           <graphic>
                              <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="HOME" size="1.5em" />
                           </graphic>
                           <font>
                              <Font size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXButton>
                     </graphic>
                </TitledPane>
              </panes>
            </Accordion>
         </children>
      </VBox>
```

I want output like this

[image]

What I'm getting is

[image]

In Scene Builder all components showing up properly, but when I'm running project with netbeans Button text not rendering.
Please help me to achieve desired output.

Comment: You haven't set any text in the buttons

Comment: But Button Text is showing in Scene Builder, see as per first picture @James_D

Comment: I assume that's just a placeholder that Scene Builder provides. But there's no text in the FXML.

Comment: Okay got this Scene Builder not setting Text property when saving FXML file, Thanks James_D